How can I group a list of folders into roughly equal groups by number of files in each folder?
I have a table in SQL Server that contains references to a number of folders (usually between 50 - 100), and a count of how many files are in each folder (anywhere from 1 to a few million). The total number of files varies. I would like to be able to define a number of groups (EDIT: usually 4, sometimes up to 8), and then split the folders into this number of groups, where each group is relatively balanced in the total number of files.
I could potentially try doing something with a RANK(), where it would rank folders by their number of files and then round-robin place folders into a group (Rank 1, 5, 9, 13 in Group 1, Rank 2, 6, 10, 14 in Group 2, and so on), but that doesn't really satisfy the balancing element, especially because of the huge variance in file count across folders. NTILE() doesn't seem to really work either. I can kind of imagine how this might be possible with some sort of usage of SUM() by calculating the total number of files across the entire table, and using that plus the desired number of groups to create a "target value" of some sort, and then grouping with a cumulative sum without exceeding that target value. However, I think I might be overthinking that and I'm not sure how flexible that would be with the variance in file counts. Any help would be much appreciated.
Sample data (7.46 million files, across 74 folders):
CREATE TABLE HypotheticalValues(SubFolder varchar(50), FileCount int);
INSERT INTO HypotheticalValues
VALUES ('Folder_01',1641315),('Folder_02',1455152),('Folder_03',844307),('Folder_04',832644),('Folder_05',450814),('Folder_06',374512),('Folder_07',343619),('Folder_08',227136),('Folder_09',167329),('Folder_10',164884),('Folder_11',148423),('Folder_12',94408),('Folder_13',92737),('Folder_14',84281),('Folder_15',73686),('Folder_16',58376),('Folder_17',56164),('Folder_18',34627),('Folder_19',29531),('Folder_20',29278),('Folder_21',28901),('Folder_22',28473),('Folder_23',27756),('Folder_24',24234),('Folder_25',23026),('Folder_26',22009),('Folder_27',18153),('Folder_28',17066),('Folder_29',12946),('Folder_30',10221),('Folder_31',7393),('Folder_32',6710),('Folder_33',6339),('Folder_34',5002),('Folder_35',4525),('Folder_36',2988),('Folder_37',2749),('Folder_38',2718),('Folder_39',2419),('Folder_40',1661),('Folder_41',569),('Folder_42',381),('Folder_43',233),('Folder_44',217),('Folder_45',209),('Folder_46',151),('Folder_47',134),('Folder_48',115),('Folder_49',103),('Folder_50',80),('Folder_51',60),('Folder_52',60),('Folder_53',54),('Folder_54',48),('Folder_55',24),('Folder_56',18),('Folder_57',15),('Folder_58',15),('Folder_59',10),('Folder_60',8),('Folder_61',8),('Folder_62',5),('Folder_63',4),('Folder_64',4),('Folder_65',4),('Folder_66',3),('Folder_67',2),('Folder_68',2),('Folder_69',2),('Folder_70',2),('Folder_71',2),('Folder_72',1),('Folder_73',1),('Folder_74',1);

Example desired result (@ NumGroups = 4):
SubFolder       FileCount   Group
------------------- 
Folder_01       1641315     1
Folder_12       94408       1
Folder_19       29531       1
Folder_20       29278       1
Folder_21       28901       1
Folder_28       17066       1
Folder_29       12946       1
Folder_30       10221       1
Folder_44       217         1
Folder_45       209         1
Folder_46       151         1
Folder_47       134         1
Folder_48       115         1
Folder_49       103         1   
Folder_64       4           1
Folder_65       4           1
Folder_66       3           1
Folder_67       2           1
Folder_68       2           1
Folder_69       2           1
Folder_70       2           1
Folder_71       2           1
Folder_72       1           1
Folder_73       1           1
Folder_74       1           1  -- 1864619 files total
Folder_02       1455152     2
Folder_07       343619      2
Folder_25       23026       2
Folder_26       22009       2
Folder_27       18153       2
Folder_39       2419        2
Folder_40       1661        2
Folder_41       569         2
Folder_42       381         2
Folder_43       233         2
Folder_57       15          2
Folder_58       15          2
Folder_59       10          2
Folder_60       8           2
Folder_61       8           2
Folder_62       5           2
Folder_63       4           2  -- 1867287 files total
Folder_03       844307      3
Folder_06       374512      3
Folder_09       167329      3
Folder_10       164884      3
Folder_15       73686       3
Folder_16       58376       3
Folder_17       56164       3
Folder_18       34627       3
Folder_24       24234       3
Folder_23       27756       3
Folder_31       7393        3
Folder_32       6710        3
Folder_33       6339        3
Folder_34       5002        3
Folder_35       4525        3
Folder_36       2988        3
Folder_37       2749        3
Folder_38       2718        3  -- 1864299 files total
Folder_04       832644      4
Folder_05       450814      4
Folder_08       227136      4
Folder_11       148423      4
Folder_13       92737       4
Folder_14       84281       4
Folder_22       28473       4
Folder_50       80          4
Folder_51       60          4
Folder_52       60          4
Folder_53       54          4
Folder_54       48          4
Folder_55       24          4
Folder_56       18          4  -- 1864852 files total

In this example, I chose to separate the data into 4 groups, which works out to ~1.865 million files in each group. On some projects, splitting into more groups (up to 8) would be appropriate. This division does not have to be exact, it just has to be a rough estimate. (EDIT: "Rough" here generally means within around 200,000 of each other, maybe a little more for the largest folder or two.)

Sounds like the knappsac problem which is complicated to solve in sql server without testing all combinations which is slow. You could order it by file size and do a running sum aggregate and split groups by running sum / (total sum / group count), but it won't be perfect either

It is similar to the knapsack problem in that I'm trying to figure out how to pack various items by weight or other value into a knapsack, but there is a difference in that there are no hard limits. If I have 4 knapsacks, and they each need to hold 4 million files, that's fine. If I decide to expand it to 8 knapsacks and they each hold 2 million instead, that's fine too. Basically, I would decide the number of knapsacks at run time, and then roughly split it accordingly.

Sounds like a harder knappsac problem. What do you need the result for? Perhaps whatever you're doing isn't needed?

The result will be used to create a series of batched file transfers. I generate these files by category, and then those files all need to be moved into a new environment via CLI. I could transfer all of the subfolders by transferring the parent folder in one command, but it is dramatically faster to split it up into multiple batches, and keeping the file counts balanced makes sure that I don't give up that efficiency by doing something like one batch handling 3 million files and another only handling 1 million..

The comment thread got deleted when you deleted your answer, but again, "roughly" was always intended to be within a couple hundred thousand files. I've now more clearly defined that in the problem, along with providing more robust sample data.
Regarding your other question, the files involved are consistently large in number, but small in size - usually <10 KB. Given that file size isn't a significant variable, the primary vector to balance file transfers across multiple batches running separate processes is the number of files.

I would think about why you are batching in principle. If you are doing this since multiple batches are more efficient, then there is an approximate upper limit of the batch size. In which case you probably count the total files, divide by your upper limit and that sets your number of batches. Then you'll be getting a roughly similar transfer time per batch & a volume that you're comfortable monitoring. If you want different numbers of groups, tune the volume accordingly.
